# Process Builder to Update Opportunity Product Line with Revenue Scheduling on

Tags: process-builder, opportunity-lineitem

I have used process builder to add two product lines to an opportunity based on a set criteria from a custom object.

This works seamlessly and is great when we are working with brand new records. However the custom object looks at Project work and sometimes the cost and revenue benefit can change value and month.

We currently in our custom object have 4 fields that are subject to change:

- Project Benefit
- Payback Month
- Project Cost
- Cost Month

Within the Opportunity I have created 2 products - Project Cost & Project Benefit both with Revenue Scheduling attached to map over 12 months.

Essentially what I want to do is if any of the 4 fields on the custom object are changed is to update the opportunity / the product lines and therefore the revenue scheduling.

I have used the process builder and said to update a record on the OpportunityLineItems and reference the Sales Price to update from the custom object, however this isn't working and isn't firing back an error.

Comment: I may be a bit off here, but depending on the type of Opportunity, when Revenue Scheduling changes you may or may not be changing the OLI or the Sales Price on the Opportunity. It depends on how the Opp is priced. If fixed priced, Opp Price doesn't change, only the cost of making/selling the product changes so you may not be updating the Sales Price. Make certain you understand the type of sales process you're working with.

Comment: Are you using field updates in the process or calling a flow? This post from the success community recommends the latter. Came here with a similar question, so can't help much beyond that! https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000svkLQAQ